# Twitter integration works on most device throws exception for twitter.getAccountSettings() on some devices

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have integrated `twitter API` in my android application, yes it works on majority of the devices.

But on some devices after the `login` is successfully done, when ever before tweeting i again do the checking using the `isAuthenticated()` which further calls the `twitter.getAccountSettings();` an exception is thrown.

The log is shown below for the Exception thrown.

```
                10-09 20:08:09.030: W/System.err(22614): -1:
        10-09 20:08:09.030: W/System.err(22614): Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0ae6f91b or
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=029022e3
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[0ae6f91b-029022e3], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.11}
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:199)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:75)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:103)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at twitter4j.Twitter.getAccountSettings(Twitter.java:1440)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at com.ocatalog.socialmedia.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:24)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at com.ocatalog.SettingsActivity$CheckCredentailTask.doInBackground(SettingsActivity.java:320)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at com.ocatalog.SettingsActivity$CheckCredentailTask.doInBackground(SettingsActivity.java:1)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
        10-09 20:08:09.040: W/System.err(22614):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

Any help would prove as a boon , as i am not able to understand what is the issue on some of the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this was simply caused because I had crossed the limit of posts that were provided by twitter.

As the error message explains nothing, it was really confusing, if anyone faces the same type of issue do wait for 24 hours for your application to start working again.

And I didn't get why it was failing on only some of the devices and not for all, if at all any one gets the answer to this do let me know.